# How to retrieve the register information of the specified thread in Linux?

Tags: c, linux, unix, cpu-registers

Look this:

```
(gdb) info reg
rax            0x7ffff00008c0   140737219922112
rbx            0x7ffff7fe9700   140737354045184
rcx            0x33d9e182a0 222698767008
rdx            0x7ffff7fe9a10   140737354045968
rsi            0x7ffff00008c0   140737219922112
rdi            0x0  0
rbp            0x7ffff7fe8e50   0x7ffff7fe8e50
rsp            0x7ffff7fe8e30   0x7ffff7fe8e30
r8             0x400afb 4197115
r9             0x0  0
r10            0x7ffff7fe8bb0   140737354042288
r11            0x33d9c0c480 222696621184
r12            0x33d9c11200 222696641024
r13            0x7ffff7fe99c0   140737354045888
r14            0x0  0
r15            0x3  3
rip            0x4008c1 0x4008c1 <write_to_thread_log(char const*)+29>
eflags         0x246    [ PF ZF IF ]
cs             0x33 51
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x0  0
es             0x0  0
fs             0x0  0
gs             0x0  0
```

My question is:
Which interface can realize this function in Linux?
My platform ：Linux 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Note I removed the "core" tag, because it's so ambiguous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [**`ptrace`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ptrace) system call is the standard debugging facility in Linux, which GDB uses to interact with other processes being debugged.  GDB probably gets this information with the `PTRACE_GETREGS` or `PTRACE_GETREGSET` requests.

- [`ptrace`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace) man page

Comment: thanks. 
The ptrace() system call provides a means by which a parent process may observe and control the execution of another process.
But how to get the register information of the specified thread.
Like Windows-API:GetThreadContext().

Comment: Using the `PTRACE_GETREGS` parameter, like Jonathon said.

Comment: Would you give me a demo? 
Like this: 
 void func(pthreat_t tid, void *reg_info)
 {
  //?
 }

Comment: @JonathonReinhart about ptrace(), I only saw the 'pid_t' parameter, but where is the 'pthread_t' parameter?

Comment: pid_t is int, pthread_t is unsigned long. How  to convert pthread_t to a pid_t? It is not safe.

Comment: Read this [ptrace man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/ptrace.2.html). It involves a bit of reading, but you will know how to do it then. Google might help too. Try something like "ptrace threads". I think I saw an article on Linux Journal about it when I did that, so it's bound to be descriptive.